# Powershell query object in structure by name

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an Powershell object generated from the following XML structure (it comes from a SOAP web service):

```xml
<item>
  <id>123</id>
  <newAttrs>
    <item>
      <name>uid</name>
      <values>
        <item>nUser1</item>
      </values>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name>cn</name>
      <values>
        <item>some user name</item>
      </values>
    </item>
  </newAttrs>
</item>
```

But beware that this is really an object and not an xml anymore. So I can access for example the id by `$item.id`

I'd like to know if I can access similary the value(s) of items in the newAttrs array. So I am thinking of something like `$item.newAttrs[name="uid"].Values` Or do I have to iterate over the newAttrs array?

Does anything like this exist? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's an [example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbis.html).

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean there?

Comment: Humm, never mind. That's a Java implementation to parse XML SOAP objects, sorry.

Comment: There's a working example in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20562437/2596334), but the author is complaining that it's slow...

Comment: Yeah basically there it's also just iterating over the nodes. I already have this but was looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the .SelectNodes() method will accomplish what you are looking for:

```
$item.SelectNodes("//newAttrs[contains(name,""uid"")]").values
```

Or if you only want the item's text you can append `.InnerText` to the end of that command.

**Edit:** Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought it was the XML but you only knew how to reference it as if it were an object. So if I understand correctly you should have an object structured something like this:

```
$item = [pscustomobject]@{
    "id" = '123'
    'newAttr' = [pscustomobject]@{
        'uid' = 'nUser1'
        'cn' = 'some user name'
    }
}
```

Where $item has two properties, 'id' and 'newAttr'. 'id' is a string, and 'newAttr' is a nested object that has two properties, those being 'uid' and 'cn', both of which are strings. If that is the case you can reference the 'uid' property simply by referencing it like so:

```
$item.newAttr.uid
```

Does that accomplish what you were looking to do, or am I misunderstanding still?

**Edit2:** Ok, since this is an array of objects it sounds like you're already doing it the best way that I know of I assume:

```
$item.newAttr | Where{$_.name -eq 'uid'} | Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

That will give you the value of the 'Value' property for each item in the array where the 'Name' property equals 'uid'.

Comment: As I wrote above $item is not a XML structure but an object. So unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I have updated my answer, hopefully it better represents your situation now.

Comment: No problem. But that doesn't cut it either. The nested object newAttr is an array with a list of "name" attributes which are associated with "values".

Comment: You mean it is an array of objects, and those objects have 'name' and 'value' properties? Or is it a hashtable?

Comment: Yes the first. It's not a hash table unfortunately

Comment: Ok, I updated it with the best way that I know of to do what you want. I'm guessing you are already doing this or something similar. If not, I hope this is an improvement for you.

Comment: The last one works great! I was looking for something like this. thx! Just a minor thing: it's `newAttrs` with an s

Comment: One last question: How does this compare performance-wise to a loop over the newAttrs array if I want to get let's say 10 values out of 100 items in newAttrs?

Comment: It should be near instant to be honest. You can check it out yourself with `measure-command{code goes here} `